# How to write a command line interface in Swift 4 with features similar to Unix man pages?

Tags: swift, terminal, command-line-interface, user-input, swift4

For example; go ahead and open a terminal window and type:

```
man ls
```

Have a look around; notice that you can move up and down through text **with the arrow keys** and that the terminal history is now missing.

> Use "q" to quit.

The terminal history is now returned.

I'm trying to understand how to write an interface that does the above: with the terminal history disappearing and reappearing on exit and **most importantly with the interface being able to take key presses as input** instead of using readLine().

On the screen clearing front I've managed an ANSI escape code:

```
print("\u{001B}[2J")
```

Which clears the screen and starts the cursor from the bottom but is only really implementing newlines and pushing the old content off the screen unlike the man pages which remove the scrollable history. So currently not what I'm trying to achieve.

As for taking key presses as input, I haven't been able to find much but **Foundation** has 3 references to:

> standardInput

The Developer Documentation lists them in **FileHandle, NSUserUnixTask & Process**. I'm hoping perhaps one of them may be able to listen for key presses and then respond with a notification that I can use to update my interface with the correct screen clear and repositioning of text or perform an action (like quitting and returning to the normal prompt as "man" does with the press of "q").

Would love to have some help on this one, thanks!

Comment: FYI - when you run `man ls` and then interact with the output, you are actually now running the `more` (or `less`) command depending on the value of the `PAGER` environment variable. So what you are asking is how to implement something similar to the `more` or `less` commands.

Comment: @rmaddy This is correct; however I am mainly after how they implement the two main features listed above.

Answer (score 0):

The standard macOS Cocoa GUI uses events; representing mouse clicks, keyboard presses, etc.; to communicate user input to your app. Read up on event handling and you can make your app quit which the user types a "q". That is the underlying mechanism for keyboard input and the alternative to your `readLine()`.

However what you are describing is more involved than just key press handling, you want terminal-like screen control; scrolling backwards, clearing the screen, etc. The original way of doing this on Unix was to use low-level tty device interfaces and issue control codes the screens themselves understood. The modern was is often to implement these same control codes in your Cocoa interface, this allows the output of the standard Unix-level commands; e.g. man *et al*; to be interpreted. This is what *Terminal.app* does. The standard Cocoa text controls also implement support for some of this, in particular a subset of Emacs-style cursor movement is supported.

The open source *iTerm2* is an Objective-C alternative to *Terminal.app*, the source is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2). If you read this you can learn how to implement a terminal window interface in Cocoa in Objective-C, you'll have to figure out the Swift equivalent.

HTH